# Visual Studio Comment and code highlighting stops

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

Using Visual Studio 2017 and after a while several shortcuts stop working. CTRL+K+C and KU for uncommenting just stops working. Also, noticed that the expand/collapse code block disappears.

[image]

[image]

Closing Visual Studio and Re-opening solves the problem for about 20 minutes to an hour. After that the problem seems to start again. Any ideas? This is getting pretty annoying.

EDIT: This only appears to be a problem in .js files. Expand/Collapse and Commenting works in .html and .cs files

Comment: Go to menu, Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard and then on right side of form press Reset button. Let us know does this work for you

Comment: It does not. Throws a prompt "Keyboard mappings will reset to their default values. Continue?" but the behavior does not change.

Comment: Press Yes button. All of those shortcuts are the default for Visual Studio

Comment: I pressed yes, problem still exists. The only way to fix this problem is to close and re-open the project. Notice the buttons are grayed and the code collapse features are also missing.